# Which is the best replacement for KProf?

Tags: c++, profiling

I'm searching for a "good enough" gprof output visualizer. Kprof seems unmaintained.

Profiling is an important part of (speed sensitive) applications development, but I fail to find support on the major Linux IDEs.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: google-perftools cpu-profile with kcachegrind for visualization seems the way to go for me.

http://google-perftools.googlecode.com
http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439060/is-it-possible-to-get-a-graphical-representation-of-gprof-results | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274095/view-gprof-output-in-kcachegrind

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [KCachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) to vizualize the logs given by [oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/news/).

Comment: It does appear, if you know what to look for, that KCachegrind can get line and instruction level inclusive costs. So they're getting there, and that's good.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you're looking for, but for me, gprof with an editor with decent search does the job.  Are you looking for in what case the top X functions are called so you can optimise them or do you want a nice call-graph of your application?

Comment: I would like a tool to inspect the call trees and how much time is spent on each call; preferably in a visual way.