# Diagram of the routines used in the execution of a Fortran code

Tags: debugging, fortran, gdb

I am trying to modify a complex Fortran code for fluid dynamics written by many people which consists of many routines, subroutines, and functions. I wonder if there is an option in gdb or any other debugger or code that can generate a diagram of the routines called when the code is executed with a specific option. I am looking to generate a diagram like this or similar where I can see all the routines and subroutines that were called when executing Fortran the code, so I can have an idea about what routines to modify. [image]

Comment: Which platform? truss and dtrace can show function call traces, but aren’t available everywhere.

Comment: Most profilers, including gprof, can generate a call graph from run time information - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439060/is-it-possible-to-get-a-graphical-representation-of-gprof-results might be of use

Comment: I am running the code on a Mac and Linux server.

Comment: I used to use Understand from https://www.scitools.com/ for diagramming Fortran code bases.  Very useful.  Costs money.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use a debugger it would probably be more common to use the output of a profiler - [Is it possible to get a graphical representation of gprof results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439060/is-it-possible-to-get-a-graphical-representation-of-gprof-results) provides a few suggestions, and below is the output generated by using `gprof` and `gprof2dot` on one of my own little codes

[image]