# View gprof output in kcachegrind

Tags: profiling, gprof, kcachegrind, callgrind

How to view output of gprof in kcachegrind? Is here a converter from gcc's gmon.out into callgrind.out?

Answer (score 5):

Currently, this seems not to be supported. It is mentioned on [Kcachegrind's whishlist](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Bugs.html), though.

Comment: Ok, I see this line. Is there any progress in turning this part of wishlist into real-world software?